# Full screen webcam background

Tags: background, three.js, video-streaming

I have tried [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sv6sLk6j/8/) and can't get the background canvas to be at full size of the window. I have tried `video.width = window.innerWidth` but with no luck. Can some explain?
[image: T]

**update**:

the problem i think is with this code (and if this is the case I think the title should be *"Give PlaneGeometry the dimensions of `window.innerWindth, window.innerHeight`"*

```
//the geometry on which the movie will be displayed;
//movie image will be scaled to fit these dimensions.
movieGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 2,2,0 );
movieScreen = new THREE.Mesh( movieGeometry, movieMaterial );
// movieScreen.position.set(0,50,0);
movieScreen.material.depthTest = false;
movieScreen.material.depthWrite = false
```

when I change the parameters of the PlaneGeometry the movie image will be scaled to fit these dimensions. The problem is that I can't find the right dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

`body` has a margin.
add:

```
body {
  margin: 0px;
}
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2pha/sv6sLk6j/11/)

Comment: your example is not working.. if you strech the result to have bigger width and then click RUN you will see the same results as the image i have posted

Comment: I thought you were talking about the borders/margin. Do you even need the video on a material if it is just for a background? Why not have a video behind the three.js scene?

Comment: you might be right.. I will try to have the video on a video element outside the scene